# Error creating AzureAffinityGroup

Tags: powershell, azure

I am  running below commands:

```
New-AzureAffinityGroup -Name $AfGroup -Location $Location -Label $AfGroup -Description $AfGroup
```

But getting below error:

```
New-AzureAffinityGroup : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: managementCertificate
```

I am deleting %appdata%\Windows Azure Powershell xml file then adding azure account but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: So what are you setting `$AfGroup` to?

Comment: I am initializing all the variable value before executing this command.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the Azure PowerShell module
2. Install the latest version of the Azure PowerShell module from here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/issues
3. Run `Remove-AzureAccount`, because we do not want to use Active Directory authentication (tokens expire after a few hours)
4. Run `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile` to download your subscription details locally
5. Run `Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile` to import the subscription details from the "publish settings file"

Try to re-run your script after the above steps.

Comment: I have done all these but getting same error.. i m not able to identify what is exact problem.